# ¿Cómo evito que mi ciclo for se haga infinito? C++

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Quiero incrementar mi variable "peso" de uno en uno, y cuando esta variable sea igual a su valor inicial multiplicado por 10 se detenga mi ciclo for.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for(int peso=2;peso<=peso*10;peso++){
     cout<<peso<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Imprime el peso y lo va aumentando pero nunca se detiene.

Comment: peso siempre será menor que peso * 10 mientras peso sea mayor que cero. Y peso arranca en 2 sin que nada en tu código lo cambie de valor.

Answer (score 2):

Dos problemas

1. Estás reevaluando el límite en cada ciclo del `for`. Tu límite, en general, no debe variar durante la ejecución del `for`. En tu caso, el límite es una expresión que varía en cada ciclo.
2. Estas comparando un valor contra si mismo (esencialmente). La expresión `peso<=peso*10` siempre te va a dar **verdadero**, pues compara el peso contra 10 veces el mismo peso. Entonces, el `for` nunca se detiene.

**Solución**

Calcula el límite antes del `for`:

```
int limite = peso * 10;
for(int peso=2;peso <= limite;peso++){
 cout<<peso<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Es que pones peso =<peso *10
y luego lo incrementas.
En lugar de peso =<peso *10 tienes que poner en cuál peso se detiene o alguna variable a la cual no debe superar

Comment: Algo de código para apoyar tu argumento no vendría mal. No todos tenemos la capacidad de abstracción para ver el codigo en nuestra mente. Además, eso le daría mayor relevancia a tu respuesta. Puedes leer [answer]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

mira,  lo que sucede es que dentro del bucle, cada vez que sucede el peso++, se modifica el maximo, es decir luego de la primera vuelta, el maximo no seria 20 sino 30 y asi consecutivamente, es decir se te hace infinito, lo que puede hacer es:

1. Declarar el maximo fuera del bucle

2.reemplazarlo por while

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int peso=2;
    int pesoTotal = peso*10;

    while(peso<=pesoTotal)
    {
        cout<< peso << endl;
        peso++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

espero te sirva amigo !.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo la siguiente parte de codigo o elaborar sobre la misma.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i;
for(int i=2;i<=peso*10;i++){
 cout<<i<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```